# Tricky situation calling variable with ÅÄÖ and & afterwards

Tags: variables, get, special-characters

I have these tricky problems.

On my site I allow registrations with the characters `åäö` in them, and I have friendly URLs linking to their profile, so lets say an URL looks like this:

[example.com/profile/åäöismyname/](http://example.com/profile/%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6ismyname/)

and the `userfriendly` variable is `$_GET['vanlig']`.

Now, this is called [example.com/profile/åäömyname&favorisera](http://example.com/profile/%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6myname&favorisera)

`$_GET['vanlig']` is now called as `åäömyname&favorisera` instead of `åäömyname`, and `&favorisera` is not called.

This works perfectly fine as long as I don't have `åäö` in the `$_GET` variable, `&favorisera` is then called properly.

Any suggestions to this? Changing their friendly names is not an option. Since this may cause duplicate names in the DB.

I'm using nginx as a webserver for friendly URLs.

EDIT:

i tried this

```
$userid = urlencode($userid);

<div class="privat" onclick="window.location = '/profil/<?=$userid?>&favorisera'" style="cursor:pointer;" title=""></div>
```

without any success, the linking shows ( as an actual example from the source code ) :

```
<div class="privat" onclick="window.location = '/profil/k%C3%A5taelin&favorisera'" style="cursor:pointer;" title=""></div>
```

When clicked, i return a var dump of $_GET['vanlig'], which results in string(19) "kåtaelin&favorisera" anyway.

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language so that people familiar with that language will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a question mark to start the query string.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the question is already sent via the friendly URLS like this profil.php?id=2312

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand is a special character signifying a new variable, so try using [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on your strings for the links, and then [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) when you manipulate it in your page or database.